# Run shortcut as administrator on startup

Tags: windows-8.1

Using Windows 8.1, UAC disabled. I have a script that sets up some static ARP entries. It needs elevated privileges and no user interaction. I accomplish this by creating a shortcut to it and setting it to run as administrator.

This needs to run on startup. Currently I do this by placing it in the Startup folder of the start menu (via explorer as Windows 8 has no traditional start menu).

However, it does not run on startup. I have discovered that Windows 8 simply ignores anything in the Startup folder that runs as administrator.

How do I run this on startup as administrator?

I also tried setting it to start via the task scheduler, but same result. Tasks that run elevated are ignored.

The user account has administrator privileges but is not "administrator" or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the script to run as administrator, then use task schedular and run it with highest privileges, but under your own user. This will execute the script as SYSTEM, but use your environment.

Do note that when you run something as administrator, it will run in its own environment. So it is possible your script works, but that it behaves unexpectedly because its in its own environment. To be sure, you can see the task scheduler results from last run, and you can run it once on demand to troubleshoot.

Comment: When I set it to run as administrator in task scheduler, it silently does not run. However, I just now was able to make it work by running as the current user in the scheduler but also checking "run with highest privileges", and also not setting the script itself to run as admin as you suggested. You helped me find that. If you want to add that to the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Its what I meant, but you're right, it wasn't worded properly. I edited the post.

Answer (score -1):

I have a program that I run as administrator at startup. As you know, Windows normally blocks this. You need a program to run as standard which then launches your executable.

There are several on the net - may I suggest ELEVATE.EXE:

http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/